# Managing MySQL setting on Ubuntu Lunix 16.4 when automatic unattended upgrade happens

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I just had MySQL 5.7.25 upgraded automatically in unattended mode and the settings I had set for ExecStart disappeared.
How do I preserve the ExecStart setting so I am not blind side on the next automatic unattended upgrade.

The ExecStart  settings were in the file:

lib/systemd/system/mysql.service:

```
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
# Normally, we'd simply use:
# ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --sql-mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered after reading the post on

https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

You will need to make the changes to a folder so that it is protected from the automatic unattended upgrade that happens periodically on Ubuntu Linux (especially MySQL):

```
sudo systemctl edit mysql
```

This will put you in an editor and you will need to enter the following:

```
[Service]

ExecStart=

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --sql-mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

The first ExecStart clears whatever setting this variable had been set as.  The  next ExecStart will set up the variable with the proper option for starting mysql.    

After saving this, it will create a file called override.conf  in the folder mysql.service.d   i.e. in /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d





The file  /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service should look as follows:
 # MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]

User=mysql

Group=mysql

PermissionsStartOnly=true

ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld

ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post

TimeoutSec=600

Restart=on-failure

RuntimeDirectory=mysqld

RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
```

You will need to restart the MySQL server so  do the following:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service mysql restart
```